# use of include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT) in android.mk

Tags: android, android-build

I am adding 1 external jar in my application , and in my android.mk file  like

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := mytest:robotium-solo-3.1.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

Can anyone tell exactly what is the use of this "include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)"

Answer (score 5):

Resurrecting this from the dead but, if you follow the make file tree you'll see that `BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT` includes (thus calls) the contents of the `multi_prebuilt.mk` file where you can see the specifics of what it does, but basically it includes all the prebuilt jar files that you have added to the `LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` file.